# How do I determine the parent repository of a git repository?

Tags: git, dvcs

When I do a `git pull` my repository automatically pulls from the original git repo that I cloned from.  How can I get the URL of that git repository from the child repository?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Also, `git remote -v` will show the urls of all your remotes.

Comment: it shows the list of repos that I had cloned. what if I had not cloned the parent ever?

Comment: All your repository knows about are its remotes. If you created your repository by cloning, it will automatically have a remote called "origin" pointing at the URL it was cloned from. But it doesn't have any concept of where that origin repository came from. Is that what you're asking about?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`git remote`](http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html):

```
git remote show
```

This will list all the remotes. Then, for example:

```
git remote show origin
```